# silverlight application merging with aspx project . not updating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, xap

I am currently doing a Silverlight project on esri map and also doing a website on aspx for me to display the map within the website.

I am using C# for both but had encountered a problem merging both projects together. I understand that when a Silverlight project runs, it would produce a xap page in the Silverlight project client bin folder. So, for me to display the map within the website, I created a client bin folder in aspx project and dragged the xap from my Silverlight project into the folder.

However, the xap page in my aspx website does not update whenever changes are made to my Silverlight project's database.  Is this because I have to merge both projects together so that they use the same database? I have copied the app data from the website application to the silverlight's app data folder too.

Why cant it update?

aspx contains soundsensor c# project,  the main website with a app data folder
sliverlight contains silverlight application and silverlightapplication.web with a app data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it right, you don't need to create the ClientBin folder yourself. By doing this yourself, that means the XAP file does not get updated when you hit Build.

- Go to your web project.
- **Delete** your **ClientBin** folder you created.
- Right click on your
  web project and select **Properties**, then go to the **Silverlight
  Applications** tab and add your Silverlight project to it.

That should do the trick.

Comment: i have created a new sliver light project by adding it from the main website with only one client bin in the whole solution. which means now i only have 1 main website,  1 silver light application and 1 sound sensor c# project. Everything works fine now and i have tried your method , it works too! hope this helps anyone who encountered the same error as me (: